# Spring Boot integration test with Spock: stubbed method returns null

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, integration-testing, raspbian, spock

I'm creating a java app for raspberry pi using Pi4j.

The application fails to run out of raspbian OS due to lack of GPIO drivers in place. That's why when I run my spock integration tests I need to mock/stub a bean which relies on original Pi4j API. My problem is that the bean itself is mocked but the stubbed method returns null instead of the value I define.

```
@SpringBootTest
class RoboApplicationTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context

    @SpringBean
    GpioController gpioController = Stub()

    def "test context loads"() {
        given:
        gpioController.provisionDigitalInputPin(_, _, _) >> { throw new RuntimeException("I'm stubbed!") }

        expect:
        context != null
        context.containsBean('gpioController')
    }
}
```

Instead of throwing an exception or returning anything I put there "provisionDigitalInputPin" method returns null that causes further NPE.

You can find the whole app here: https://github.com/ahlinist/raspberry-pi4j/tree/feature/integration-tests

I'm trying to achieve the result described here: https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-spring/boot-test/src/test/groovy/org/spockframework/boot/SpringBeanIntegrationSpec.groovy

I've tried many approaches with no result. Similar test with Mockito works well. What am I missing?

**Update:** To run integration tests execute:

```
./gradlew integrationTest
```

**Update 2:** The corresponding [Spock ticket #1084](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1084) has been created on GitHub.

Comment: @kriegaex so you know how to make it work?

Comment: OMG, I posted this comment under the wrong question when I was going through my list of questions to follow up on. Wrong browser tab, sorry for the noise. I am going to delete this comment and the previous one again.

Answer (score 0):

When I clone your project and run the test, I also see a NPE, ...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:778) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    (...)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at robot.controller.impl.RaspberryPiInputImpl.addListener(RaspberryPiInputImpl.java:19) ~[main/:na]
    at robot.sensor.AbstractSensor.init(AbstractSensor.java:21) ~[main/:na]
    at robot.TwoWheelRobot.init(TwoWheelRobot.java:20) ~[main/:na]
    at robot.RoboApplication.run(RoboApplication.java:26) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

... but not in your test but in [this class](https://github.com/ahlinist/raspberry-pi4j/blob/feature/integration-tests/src/main/java/robot/controller/impl/RaspberryPiInputImpl.java):

```java
package robot.controller.impl;

import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalInput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinListenerDigital;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import robot.controller.Input;
import robot.controller.Listener;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RaspberryPiInputImpl implements Input {

    private final GpioPinDigitalInput gpioPinDigitalInput;

    @Override
    public void addListener(Listener listener) {
        GpioPinListenerDigital gpioListener = (GpioPinListenerDigital) listener;
        gpioPinDigitalInput.addListener(gpioListener);
    }
}
```

You have a final `GpioPinDigitalInput` field there which never gets initialised, i.e. it will always be `null`. So what else than a NPE do you expect when calling the `addListener(..)` on it? Maybe you should inject a value there...

Besides, I had to move the test from *src/integration-test* to *src/test*, otherwise Gradle would not run it and IntelliJ IDEA also not recognise it as a test class.

Comment: I've updated a question with a hint about how to run integration tests: ./gradlew integrationTest

Input is not injected but passed to a constructor with an application. This is exactly the issue that instead of input my stubbed method returns null.

Comment: As I said, IDEA does not recognise your integration test source directory, so something seems to be wrong with your Gradle configuration. Anyway, as for your problem: I didn't notice that you use constructor injection because the constructor is not visible as you add it via Lombok annotation. But even if I replace it by a manually created constructor the problem persists. I can confirm that your mock is being injected but that the stubbed method is not being called. Maybe there is some limitation or quirk in Spock's Spring integration. I am not a Spring user, so I am not sure.

Comment: I moved the integrationTest task from "other" group to "verification". Can you see it now? In case of single constructor spring injects the beans as its arguments. And yes, my problem is that the mock itself is injected but the stub is not returned.

Comment: Yes, that fixes the Gradle + IDE problem but not the main thing we are talking about here.

Comment: It looks as if the mock/stub has been instantiated but not yet configured with stubbed methods at the time it is used while wiring your interdependent components. Someone with more Spring + in-depth Spock expertise than I might be able to help you. Maybe you look for the Spock mailing list or open a GitHub ticket pointing to your sample project and to this SO question.

Comment: thanks to your attention to my problem. I've already created a GH issue yesterday pointing to this SO question.

Comment: Why didn't you update your question with a link? I just did that for you after searching for your ticket there.